# Editing velocity template of Liferay changes not showing or takes a while

Tags: caching, liferay, browser-cache, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I'm currently editing my **portal_normal.vm** (server/tomcat/webapps/mytheme-theme/templates) testing if I can write on the file and see it on my browser. I tried putting a test comment "<!-- test -->" just to see if I can really write on the file. So I refreshed the file and hope I can see the comment I've added, but there we're none. So I continued refreshing (ctrl+r),\ and viewing the source code for almost an twenty minutes. After a while when I tried viewing it again it reflected in my source code. So I thought it was cached by either Liferay or my browser.

So I tried tweaking the comment adding version on it ("<!-- test v2 -->"), hoping to see changes. I checked it on another browser and the comment didn't update or include my added version. So I think Liferay is responsible for the issue.

this is what my **portal-ext.properties** contain:

```
auth.token.check.enabled=false

# Database settings
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool

#For removing captch
captcha.check.portal.create_account=false

session.enable.phishing.protection=false

default.regular.theme.id=my_site_WAR_my_theme

#Delete cookies while deleting session
session.enable.persistent.cookies=false

#redirecting null problem.
redirect.url.security.mode=mysite.com

journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=

admin.email.from.name=Market.Travel Team
admin.email.from.address=admin@mysite.com

# Added because of the Error - No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread

session.enable.url.with.session.id=false
```

and my **portal-developer.properties**

```
theme.css.fast.load=false
theme.images.fast.load=false

javascript.fast.load=true
javascript.log.enabled=true

layout.template.cache.enabled=false

browser.launcher.url=

combo.check.timestamp=true

freemarker.engine.cache.storage=soft:1
freemarker.engine.modification.check.interval=0

openoffice.cache.enabled=false

velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter=true
```

**Addition:** When I tried editing the css files I can see the changes fast. Just one reload the the changes appear. I think it is just in my velocity template that take some time or there's something wrong.

**Liferay version:** Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.6 CE

Thank You!

Comment: Did you try with "Control panel -> Server administration" and clicking "Clear VM cache" and "Clear caches across the cluster" buttons?

Comment: Are you making the changes with a _diffs folder structure and are you using ant to build these within the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to define your own `portal-developer.properties`. By adding `-Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties` to your `JAVA_OPTS` in `tomcat/bin/setenv.(sh|bat)` Liferay will use it's default developer settings, which are almost identical to what you have provided. However, I do not believe this is contributes to (or could resolve) your problem. [More details here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Developer+Mode).

The developer properties do allow you to make live changes to the templates provided you are changing the right file. Due to the default `context.xml` Liferay provides to the deployed webapps, the webapps are copied/cached in `tomcat/temp/{id}-webapp-name`. This means if you change the template in `webapp/mytheme` then it may take tomcat a while to pick up on the change, if it notices the change at all (this will depend on the tomcat configuration). On the other hand, if you make a change in `temp/1-mytheme` it will show up immediately. Editing the files in the temp folder is probably not ideal, so...

**How to fix this:** (no specific order)

- Prevent Tomcat from using the temp directory for your theme. Create a `context.xml` file for your theme.

  `<Context cachingAllowed="false"/>`

  This file should be placed in the `META-INF` folder of your
  theme. If you are using the Liferay auto-deploy feature the
  context.xml file may be clobbered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566525/tomcat-6-doesnt-copy-my-context-xml), and [here](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29750). If this
  is the case you will need to find a work around that best suits your
  needs, such as modifying the context.xml after the theme is deployed.
- If you are using the Liferay Plugin-SDK the you can follow the [fast plugin development guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Fast+Plugin+Development) for setting up your development environment.