# Clearing cache in the server

Tags: caching, liferay, velocity

This is related to my problem here:

[Editing velocity template of Liferay changes not showing or takes a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051075/editing-velocity-template-of-liferay-changes-not-showing-or-takes-a-while)

I've tried to investigate the caching problem and tried different things. Here's what I found out.

I just found out that my css is also delayed in showing the updates. I tweak my css file adding comment and testing it on my browser. Now just requesting it on the URL it will just give me  an older version of the file. now if i put a query asking for version, (eg. mystyle.css?v2) it will pull the latest file and it records it. I can even see different version, eg. (mystyle.css?v1) or (mystyle.css?v2. I've cleaned my cache so it's definitely on the server side (i think).

Is there a way I can clear my cache?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you have web server in front of liferay? Which browser do you use - for IE you really should go to your "Temporary Internet Files" and delete files manually, you could disable cache altogether while testing.

Answer (score 0):

you can activate Liferay's developer setting by including the properties that are in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties.

Explanation: Liferay minifies and caches CSS and Javascript - once this is done it will not examine those for changes. The developer settings will disable that.

However, you don't want this setting active in production as this will mean that you'll have to load dozens of files instead of very few combined+minified, well cached, files.

I assume you are using this for development, not in production.

If you're having these problems in production, you should rather work with a proper theme plugin and redeploy that.